# using AJAX code in Code Igniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Its a huge question, will take you sometime to read. Sorry for this, but, I am a new web developer, I really need help, and I think its just a matter of 1-2 lines, that's why I asking you and hoping that you'll solve it in just a couple of minutes. If its not that easy, no problem, I am ready to deal with it.

Look at this code:

```
<?php
foreach($array as $value)
       {
?>
           <div>
               <div class="topic" onclick="showDetails()">
                   <h2>Topic</h2>
               </div>
               <div class="details">
                   <div>
                     <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" onkeypress="showUser()" />
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
<?php
       }
?>
```

Here, you can see, there will be some `<div>` elements, each with its own contents("topic" div, "details" div), we don't know how much of this `<div>` items will be there, because of the `foreach` loop. I want that, at first all of the "details" divs will be hidden. When I click on a topic, its following(corresponding) "details" div will be shown. For that I use `showDetails()` function. Here is the function:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".details").hide();
    }
    function showDetails()
    {
        $(this).(".details").show();
    }
</script>
```

I know why its not working, I can't detect correctly the "details" div. Can you tell me what to do ?

So, this was my 1st problrm. My Second problem is:

In the "details" div, there is an input box(`<input type="text" />`). I want my users will be able to input there and it'll be shown after being stored in the database. Its like Facebook's comment feature, we comment on a post and it gets stored and shown to us in copuple of seconds, without reloading the entire page. `showUser()` is meant to do that. What I tried for the `showUser()` function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showUser()
    {
        $(this).keypress(function(e){
           if(e.which && e.which==13)
             {
                 $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>help/comment",
                 {
                     q:this.value
                 })
             }
           else
                    {

                    }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Its a Code Igniter project, so "help" is a "Controller", and "comment" is a function in that Controller. Here is the `comment()` function:

```
public function comment()
{
    $this->load->model('model');

    $topic=array();
    $topic['user_id']=1;
    $topic['topic_id']=1;
    $topic['comment']=$_POST["q"];

    $this->model->comment($topic);
}
```

This code is not saving the user's comment in the database.

Thanks for rading this big question !

Answer (score 0):

Your questions are a bit too big & probably should be broken into two separate topics.

Briefly,

1) to link the two divs together, you will need to dynamically create individual ids. Ex:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
```

then

```
<div id="topic_<?= $key ?>"  data-id="<?= $key ?>"
```

and the same in your details section. Then in the jquery:

```
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
$("#details_"+ id).hide();  // or show()
```

That should get you started.

---

2) Can't tell from your code what $this->model->comment()  is doing; you'll just have to do some basic debugging.

I've written a tut specifically on debugging this sort of issue (and even uses CI), so have a look through here for how to debug these problems

http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2013/04/how-do-i-use-ajax-with-framework-x

Comment: Your idea is great, I am gonna try it. And "$this->model->comment()" saves the user's given comment in the database. Thanks a lot for your help. What is "data-id" ?

Comment: I know my question is disgusting, its tough to read such a big question. I'll divide the question if I don't get good answers.

Comment: Hey, its not working. This is the code:                            <div id="topic_<?php echo $key;?>" data-id="<?php echo $key;?>"                onclick="showDetails()">
         ------------------------------------------------------      </div>
<div id="details_<?php echo $key;?>"  data-id="<?php echo $key;?>">   ------------------------------------------------------------------    </div>, @jmadsen

Comment: and this is the showDetails() function:                               <script>
    function showDetails()
    {
        var id=$(this).attr('data-id');
        $("#details_"+id).hide();
    }
</script>, so I think when I click on a single "topic" <div>, its corresponding "details" <div> should be hidden, but this is not happening here. @jmadsen